# Redirect FASTAPI docs with NGINX

Tags: nginx, redirect, documentation, fastapi

I have a fastapi running on port 8020 and I am able to see swagger documentation through: localhost:8020/api/docs

When I try to redirect localhost:8020/api/docs to localhost:8080/ali/, I receive 404 error.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}



    server {
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    proxy_connect_timeout   600;
    proxy_send_timeout      600;
    proxy_read_timeout      600;
    send_timeout            600;
    client_body_timeout     600;
    listen       8080;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    autoindex off;
    
    server_name localhost;
    server_tokens off;
    location /ali/ {

       proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8020/api/docs;
       
    }
    location /p1/ {
       
       proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:80;
       
    }
        
    location /p2/ {
       
       proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:49159;
       
    }
}
}
```

The thing is that with this config, I have access to localhost:8080/p1/ and localhost:8080/p2/ but I cannot have access to localhost:8080/ali/

I am suspicious about this address that I have for getting the information: http://127.17.0.1:8020/api/docs

or the other theory is that redirecting fastapi documentation maybe is different from regular endpoints.

Comment: `127.17.0.1` should probably be `172.17.0.1`? I'm guessing it should be the same ip in every `proxy_pass`?

Comment: you mean changing resolver to 172.17.0.1?

Comment: No. One of your `proxy_pass` lines reads `http://127.17.0.1` (the one which 404s), while the other lines read `172.17.0.1`. Is there any reason why they shouldn't be the same?

Comment: sorry that was a typo. It brings the same 404 error with 172.